# How can I assign a class object to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

How can I make the pointer point at the memory location of a real object of the same class?

```
Class A
{
    int num = 0;
    A(int n) {
        this->num = n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a(10);
    A * aPtr;

    // How do I make "aPtr" point at "a"?

    // something like
    // aPtr = a; (I know this wont work but what instead)
}
```

Comment: what if I want to initialize "a" to wherever "aPtr" is pointing? I know this is a different question but I am just starting to learn this stuff. Thanks

Comment: `Class` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make "aPtr" point at "a"?

Use the `&` (address-of) operator:

```
aPtr = &a;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the address-of operator:

```
A * aPtr = &a;                 // assume that & is not overloaded
```

```
#include <memory>

A * aPtr = std::addressof(a);  // more general
```

Comment: what if I want to initialize "a" to wherever "aPtr" is pointing? I know this is a different question but I am just starting to learn this stuff. Thanks

Comment: @ProwGuitarist: Then use dereferencing: `A a = *aPtr;`